# iOS launch image is different than background image size?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have set up a launch image and this shows correctly when the app starts. In the initial view controller I do this in the viewDidLoad:

```
[self.imageBackground setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
```

Default.png is the same image as the launch image. Why does the image snaps (the image gets resized in the initial view controller) and how can I prevent this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: would be better if you grab the image from `ios device` or `simulator` (control-command-C) to copy the screen shot directly to your clipboard and create the lunch according to the size requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
```

Add `backgroundView.frame` if you are facing any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its is based on your image view size in view controller. lets set image view size same as view size in view controller.  It will reflect the same size.